# Jenkins to -1 via Gerrit Trigger if Grunt script reports errors

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs, gerrit

I am using Jenkins in combination with Gerrit Trigger and I got Jenkins user to give feedback (verify)
each time one patchset is created in Gerrit.

What I'd like to do additionally is running a Grunt script which compiles Sass and minifies Javascript and have Jenkins give a -1 feedback in case Grunt reports any error. At the moment it is not possible because even if Grunt reports errors, Jenkins marks the build as successful.

How can this behaviour be achieved and is there a standardized way to it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your Grunt script returns a non-zero [exit code](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html).

Comment: Good point. The problem I had was related: Grunt was set to forcefully keep on compiling even in case of errors.